# open-file-description table is not like what Tanenbaum described in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, ext2

In the book Modern Operating System, the author explained that if the shell script has two commands, p1 and p2 and each takes turn writing into a file x, the position where p1 finishes will be remembered by p2, as they are using the same open-file-description table. I test this with a simple script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 11 > a.txt
echo 12 > a.txt
```

It turns out that the second command overwrites the file completely.
Anything wrong with the script or the implementation?

Comment: Operation `>` (re-) **writes** the file, operation `>>` **appends** to the file. Probably, you want to use the latter one: `echo 12 >> a.txt`.

Comment: First edition was 1992 and ast was a Linux basher then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each `echo` command opens the file (and deletes the existing contents), writes to the file, and then closes it. There's no sharing at all.

To share an open file description, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 123>a.txt # open file descriptor 123 to a.txt (note that you have to choose one, bash won't choose a number)
exec 124>&123 # open file descriptor 124 as a copy of 123 (same file description)

# now we have two file descriptors pointing to the same file description
echo 11 >&123 # write to descriptor 123
echo 12 >&124 # write to descriptor 124

exec 123>&- # close file descriptor 123
exec 124>&- # close file descriptor 124
```

Of course, we're still not using two processes here, just two descriptors in one process